# Bistro chair cushion fix/replace?

Tags: wood, outdoor, furniture, diy-vs-pro

I have a pair of bistro chairs that are metal with a wire frame and have round seats. The cushions are wood (I believe) topped with foam. The seat frame is completely empty, with just a thin rim around the perimeter to hold up the cushion. They have sat out in the rain for a couple years and the wood on one of them has rotted, so the last time I sat on it, the cushion fell through.

I'm wondering whether theres any hope of fixing it. I thought about putting a couple of wood beams across the seat to hold it up, but the rotted wood of the seat is sort of rounded, so I'm not sure whether it would work to have a stiff beam underneath.

I'm open to buying new cushions, but I wouldn't know how to find the kind I need since it's such a precise thing.

My only other option is to make new cushions entirely, but I don't have a saw to cut out round wooden bases. Could this work with a hand saw?

Answer (score 1):

Whole new base & cushion is the probable best route, or at least a new base if the cushion is not as degraded as I'd expect with the wood rotting out under it.

Can it be done with a handsaw? - yes. Can *you* do it with a handsaw? Sure, if you are careful. Or you can hire someone, or have the part made  (which is another way of hiring someone.)

The usual "best powertool" for making perfect circles is a router and a circle-jig, which is effectively a compass with a point on one end and a rapidly spinning cutter (the router) on the other. A "modern" approach is to have it cut with a CNC router or CNC laser-cutter, for which there are services available for hire.

But for far less expenditure and with a good degree of care you can draw a circle with a compass that has a pencil at one end, and carefully cut to the line with a coping saw.

Answer (score 1):

**Fabric hammocks.**

1. Get strong fabric.  Ideally some synthetic stuff that is weatherproof.  You could find a piece big enough to use a whole sheet.  Or you could weave nylon webbing straps into something like a cargo net.
2. Put it over open hole in chair.
3. Wrap it around the edge of the chair seat hole and attach it to itself.  You could sew it or you could use rivets.
4. Maybe a hole for drainage in the bottom if you are going to leave it out in the rain.